# Steam doesn't work over tethered wifi, how do i solve this?

Tags: networking, proxy, android, steam, tethering

So i tried to use my android phone that is connected to a wifi, and used a wifi sharing app called (Netshare), to tether the internet to my mac(wirelessly). The internet worked, the browser works and i can even go to the steam's website through my browser, but when i try to open the steam app it says its not able to connect.Any workarounds?

[Netshare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzvFn.jpg)

[HTTP proxy setup as the app said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37I3u.png)

[HTTPS proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoXyt.png)

[cant connect to steam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmInv.png)

[Nothing works except the store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMOAo.jpg)

Ive tried google but couldn't find any relevant posts, not even on steam's website.

**edit

(Found out this has got something to do with TCP and UDP ports, mainly UDP, which the android app i mentioned doesn't seem to provide. So maybe there is a way to forward those UDP connections from the router, to my android phone and to my mac again which is tethered to the phone.Help)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the crucial part of what the application does is providing HTTP/HTTPS proxy. Services, clients, protocols etc. that don't use it just don't work.

Workaround? Connect the laptop directly or find a tethering solution that isn't so limited (I don't know if it's possible on Android though).

Answer (score 0):

You can't forward ports through tethers, so the steam ports (27000-27036) aren't being allowed. The only solution is to have a router, but to have internet you'll need an ISP so you'll have to find a deal in your area (ISP's set up the hardware for you). I suggest having over 6MB/s that is probably the minimum for steam and you can look online for how to port forward on your router.

Answer (score 0):

Just Enable Automatic Detect settings and disable proxy server in internet options > Connections > Lan Settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0LiM.png)

Answer (score 0):

On Android, under Network and Internet settings, choose Advanced, then select Private DNS to Automatic.  It should work then for loading the Steam app through Hotspot.